# How to correctly encrypt and decrypt a file using a secret key derived from a password

Tags: java, encryption, salt, jce

I am trying to work out the correct process to encrypt and decrypt a file using the "PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256" standard.

From what I understand from looking at this [example code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#PBEEx) from Oracle.

I have gathered that a salt is needed, as well as an iteration count and the hash standard.

So I have my main method, passing into the encryption method:

1. a user-defined password `new String(key).toCharArray()` as a byte array (using this method for other encryption runs)
2. a secure random IV `initVector` as a byte array
3. the plain text file `inputFile` as a String
4. the name of, to be created, ciphertext file `outputFile` as a String

I have followed the code example to code up what I believe is correct for the encrypt method. And I am storing the salt and IV to be used for decryption by appending them both to the ciphertext.

```
private static void encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] initVector, String inputFile, String outputFile) //exceptions for throws... {
    //Initalisation for encryption
    Cipher cipher;

    byte[] salt = new byte[16];

        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

        // Salt randomly generated with base64
        rand.nextBytes(salt);
        System.out.println("my salt should be" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(salt));
        salt = Base64.getEncoder().encode(salt);

        // Iteration count
        int count = 1000;

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector);
        
        // Create PBE parameter set
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(salt), count, iv);                
        // Convert pass into SecretKey object
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(new String(key).toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
        SecretKey pbeKey;
        try {
            pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, the password specified cannot be used as a secret key");
            System.out.println("Please check that your password uses valid characters");
            return;
        }

        // Create PBE Cipher
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");

        // Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
    }

    //File error checking and file handling (i.e. generating file paths)...

    System.out.println("Secret key is " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key));
    System.out.println("IV is " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(initVector));

    //Special file reading and writing with 'Cipher Stream'
    try (InputStream fin = FileEncryptor.class.getResourceAsStream(loadFile.getName());
            OutputStream fout = Files.newOutputStream(saveFile);

            CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(fout, cipher) {
            }) {
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        for(int length=fin.read(bytes); length!=-1; length = fin.read(bytes)){

                fout.write(initVector);
                fout.write(salt);

            cipherOut.write(bytes, 0, length);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong with reading and writing these files!");
        System.out.println("Please check you have the latest version of this program");
        System.out.println("Contact your IT admin to make sure you have sufficient privileges");
    }
    System.out.println("SUCCESS! Encryption finished, saved at specified location");
}
```

Then I also have my main method, passing into the decryption method:

1. a user-defined password `String inputKEY` as a string (also using this method for other dencryption runs)
2. a String for `inputIV` , has been passed in as null, since not used for PBE.
3. the ciphertext file `inputFile` as a String
4. the name of, to be created, revealplaintext file `outputFile` as a String

   private static void decrypt(String inputKEY, String inputIV, String inputFile, String outputFile) {
   Cipher cipher = null;

   ```
    //File error checking and file handling (i.e. generating file paths)...

    InputStream encryptedData = Files.newInputStream(loadFilePath);


        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(inputKEY.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
        SecretKey pbeKey = null;
        try {
            pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] initVect = new byte[16];
        encryptedData.read(initVect);

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(initVect);

        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        encryptedData.read(salt);

        PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(salt), 1000, iv);  
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");

        System.out.println("my salt should be" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Base64.getDecoder().decode(salt)));

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec); 

    try (CipherInputStream decryptStream = new CipherInputStream(encryptedData, cipher);    
            OutputStream decryptedOut = Files.newOutputStream(saveFile)){
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        for(int length=decryptStream.read(bytes); length!=-1; length = decryptStream.read(bytes)){
            decryptedOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { //This is caught when decryption is run
        System.out.println("Something went wrong with reading and writing these files!");
        System.out.println("Please check you have the latest version of this program");
        System.out.println("Contact your IT admin to make sure you have sufficient privileges");
    }

    System.out.println("SUCESS! Decryption finished, saved at specified location");
   ```

   }

I believe something is not right with my understanding of PBE, and thus the way I implemented it is probably wrong. Could anyone point out what seems to be wrong?

Comment: Are you receiving errors or is the decrypted file not equal to original file? BTW: todays iteration value should be > 10.000.

Comment: It catches on the try-catch method at the bottom of the decryption method, but still completes. And yes the decrypted file is not equal to the original file. I think there also might be a possibility of the decrypted file having a lower file size than the plain text.

Comment: It might be good idea to add the full error stack trace to your question.

Comment: It catches what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main issues are:

- IV and Salt must not be written inside the `for` loop.
- The IV is stored in `encrypt` not Base64 encoded, but is Base64 decoded in `decrypt`.
- The 16 bytes salt is stored in `encrypt` (unnecessarily) Base64 encoded, i.e. 24 bytes are stored. In `decrypt` however only 16 bytes are loaded.

Also:

- Upon encoding/decoding, sometimes no encoding is specified, so the default encoding is used.
- `encrypt` and `decrypt` use different parameter types for key and IV.
- There are many copy/paste errors in the code.

Note: In contrast to your code, the [linked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#PBEEx) code determines besides the key also the IV from password and salt.
In your code the IV is passed. Thus you have to ensure that a key/IV pair may only be used once. Usually a random IV is generated for each encryption.

In the following code (which is based on your code, but for simplicity without exception handling) these issues are fixed/optimized. Furthermore, the code applies `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` instead of your classes (but this is not required):

```java
private static void encrypt(String key, byte[] initVector, String inputFile, String outputFile) throws Exception {

    // Key
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray());
    SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
    SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

    // IV
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector);

    // Salt
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    rand.nextBytes(salt);

    // ParameterSpec
    int count = 1000; // should be larger, see Michael Fehr's comment
    PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count, iv);

    // Cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
         FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
         CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(fout, cipher)) {
    
        // Write IV, Salt
        fout.write(initVector);
        fout.write(salt);
    
        // Encrypt
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        for (int length = fin.read(bytes); length != -1; length = fin.read(bytes)) {
            cipherOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
    } 
}
```

```java
private static void decrypt(String key, byte[] initVect, String inputFile, String outputFile) throws Exception {

    try (FileInputStream encryptedData = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
         FileOutputStream decryptedOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {

        // Key
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

        // Read IV
        if (initVect == null) {
            initVect = encryptedData.readNBytes(16);
        }
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVect);

        // Read salt
        byte[] salt = encryptedData.readNBytes(16);

        // ParameterSpec
        int count = 1000;
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count, iv);

        // Cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

        try (CipherInputStream decryptStream = new CipherInputStream(encryptedData, cipher)) {
        
            // Decrypt
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = decryptStream.read(bytes); length != -1; length = decryptStream.read(bytes)) {
                decryptedOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**EDIT** - Concerning the reading of salt and IV in `decrypt`:
As *GPI* pointed out in their comment, [`FileInputStream.read(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) generally reads `b.length` bytes, but this is *not guaranteed*. More robust is to determine the length of the read data and call the method in a loop until the data is complete. Another alternative is the use of [`InputStream.readNBytes​(int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readNBytes(int)), which is *guaranteed* to read `len` bytes (unless end of stream is encountered or an exception is thrown), as *Zabuzard* has suggested. In the code, the latter is now used, i.e. `read` was replaced by `readNBytes​`.

Comment: +1. I'm not a crypto expert so I'm not judging the safety of it, but at a Java level, this  looks good to me. A minor grip, I know `FileInputStream` will "always" (if the file is long enough)  read `buffer.length` bytes when calling `read(buffer)` in any JVM implementation I've used. But it does not *have to* be so. So in your decrypt method, while reading the IV and salt, I'd definitely write the boiler-plate to make sure the actual number of bytes have been read. It would be great also security-wise because if the expected number of bytes is not reached, something fishy is going on.

Comment: Or use `readNBytes`, then you will also get back `N` bytes.

Comment: Once again cheers! I ended up using the read(), but it is certainly useful to know about readNBytes too. I think I need to do some more research myself into knowing exactly how input and output streams work...