# How to print single element of an array of Split text

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, split

I want print specific index of an Array of split text but it gives error, some one can help please

TEXT.txt contains A,B,3,D,5,1

```
        FileReader Alphabets_and_Numbers = new FileReader("TEXT.txt");
    
    Scanner read = new Scanner(Alphabets_and_Numbers);
    read.useDelimiter(",\\s*");
    
    while(read.hasNext()) {
    
    String data = read.next();
        
        String[] Alphabets = data.split("\\d");
        /*
           A
           B
           D
              */
        String[] Numbers = data.split("[^0-6]");
        /*
           3
           5
           1
             */
```

when printed with for loop is Ok it prints ABD

```
        for(int c = 0; c<Alphabets.length; c++)
        {
        
            System.out.println(Alphabets[c]);
            
        }
```

while to print single Element D, it gives
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

```
                 System.out.println(Alphabets[2]);
            }
```

Comment: along the answer as well please note (VERY IMPORTANT) the answer is handling data in the encryption as a byte array (**do not convert to the String directly**), if you want to represent binary data (ciphertext) as a String, use some sort of encoding (base64 as the most common) –

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using a random salt for the password deriving but the salt is never stored so when later decrypting (in a second run) you don't have the salt again.

Second - there is a similar issue with the initialization vector that is used for AES encryption. You don't define one on encryption side so Java is (internally)
generating one and does the encryption. Now you have to grab this iv from the cipher and save it as well for later decryption. As you don't provide the iv you run
into the exception "Missing parameter type: IV expected".

As I'm too lazy to check your code you find below the code (provided by **@Topaco**, all credits go to him ! link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719246/8166854) for
a complete file encryption / decryption that is suitable even for larger files as it uses buffered CipherInput-/OutputStreams.

**Security warning: the codehas no exception handling and is for educational purpose only!**.

code:

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class MainFileEncryption {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("File encryption with PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");

        String uncryptedFilename = "plaintext.txt";
        String encryptedFilename = "plaintext.enc";
        String decryptedFilename = "decrypted.txt";
        String password = "mySecretPassword";
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
        encrypt(password, iv, uncryptedFilename, encryptedFilename);
        decrypt(password, encryptedFilename, decryptedFilename);
    }

    // by Topaco https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719246/8166854
    private static void encrypt(String key, byte[] initVector, String inputFile, String outputFile) throws Exception {
        // Key
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        // IV
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector);
        // Salt
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        rand.nextBytes(salt);
        // ParameterSpec
        int count = 10000;
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count, iv);
        // Cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
             CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(fout, cipher)) {
            // Write IV, Salt
            fout.write(initVector);
            fout.write(salt);
            // Encrypt
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = fin.read(bytes); length != -1; length = fin.read(bytes)) {
                cipherOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void decrypt(String key, String inputFile, String outputFile) throws Exception {
        try (FileInputStream encryptedData = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
             FileOutputStream decryptedOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
            // Key
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray());
            SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
            SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            // Read IV
            byte[] initVect = new byte[16];
            encryptedData.read(initVect);
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVect);
            // Read salt
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            encryptedData.read(salt);
            // ParameterSpec
            int count = 10000;
            PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count, iv);
            // Cipher
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
            try (CipherInputStream decryptStream = new CipherInputStream(encryptedData, cipher)) {
                // Decrypt
                final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                for (int length = decryptStream.read(bytes); length != -1; length = decryptStream.read(bytes)) {
                    decryptedOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```